# In MATLAB, how can I combine 2 different `histc` results into one, and produce a 3D plot?

Tags: matlab

In one `histc`, I have latitude data. In another `histc`, I have longitude data. I have plotted the `bar` graphs of these 2 separately. Now, I want to combine them and produce a 3D graph where the x-axis is latitude, y-axis is longitude, and z-axis is the frequency with which each latitude-longitude pair occurs.

The problem is that, while plotting the graphs for latitudes and longitudes separately, I calculated their respective frequencies by taking their individual `histc`s separately. However, when I want to make it a 3D plot, I can't seem to find a way to take the `histc` of the latitude-longitude pairs.

EDIT: I am adding my code for plotting the bar graphs here upon being asked by one commenter to do so, though I don't see how that would help. The bar graph for latitude is: `bar(unique(M), histc(M,unique(M)))` and that for longitude is `bar(unique(N), histc(N,unique(N)))`. And the M and N are nx1 matrices. (Actually, they are 2 columns of a much larger matrix. But for simplicity in comprehension, I have avoided writing complex formulae here.)

EDIT: I reckon what I am looking for might be solved by surface plot, `surf`. But I am not sure. If it is, then the issue I am facing, speaking in terms of `surf`, can be stated as an issue in defining the `Z` parameter.

Comment: Take a look at `bar3`.  This allows you to plot `(x,y)` pairs and the height of the bar is reflective of each `(x,y)` pair.  However, I don't see any code that you wrote that will allow me to test if this works.

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using? `histc` has been deprecated - you should use [`histcounts`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) instead.

Comment: @rayryeng Please check the edit in the question I made. I provided the code I used for plotting the bar graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
latitudes=180*(rand(1,10000)-0.5);
longitudes=360*(rand(1,10000)-0.5);

d=[latitudes;longitudes];


minVal_Lat=-90;
maxVal_Lat=90;
minVal_Long=-180;
maxVal_Long=180;
delta=10;

axisLat=minVal_Lat:delta:maxVal_Lat;
axisLong=minVal_Long:delta:maxVal_Long;

nPDF_Lat=length(axisLat);
nPDF_Long=length(axisLong);

PDF=zeros(nPDF_Lat,nPDF_Long);

temp=0;
count_i=1;
count_j=1;

for i=axisLat;

     lowlimit_x=i-delta/2;
     upperlimit_x =i+delta/2;

         for j=axisLong;

            lowlimit_y=j-delta/2;
            upperlimit_y =j+delta/2;
            temp=0;

            for k=1:length(d(1,:)); 

                if lowlimit_x<=d(1,k) & d(1,k)<upperlimit_x
                     if lowlimit_y<=d(2,k) & d(2,k)<upperlimit_y
                         temp=temp+1;
                     else 
                     end
                else
                end
            end

            PDF(count_i,count_j)=temp;
            count_j=count_j+1;
         end
    count_i=count_i+1;
    count_j=1;
end


normFactor=sum(sum(PDF));

PDF=(1/normFactor)*PDF;


randVar_Lat=minVal_Lat:delta:maxVal_Lat;
randVar_Long=minVal_Long:delta:maxVal_Long;

surf(randVar_Lat,randVar_Long,PDF')
```

If you want get a 2D probability density function with surf plot, these codes will be worked.

Comment: Wow! Gee, thanks! I didn't realize this would be such a complicated task. If I am correct, `d` contains the latitude and longitude in the 2 rows, right? And minval and maxval are supposed to give their ranges? However, you see, I would want 2 minvals and 2 maxvals, if that is the case, because latitudes range from -90 to 90, and longitudes range from -180 to 180. And I tried changing the variables to these values, but as you know, MATLAB takes like forever to run for loops. So, what's a good solution?

Comment: I changed the code a little, With this corrected codes, you could set two different ranges. But, I don't know how to reduce processing time.

Comment: Hi. I ran the code,and the graph just got generated. But it does not exactly give what I wanted. On the Z-axis, it does not give the actual frequency of the coordinates. In fact, the max value of Z is 1, and that too only at 1 point; at all other coordinates, the Z value is 0. So, I don't want the probability density function; I want the actual number of times each coordinate appears. Could you please modify the code to do that? Thank you!

Comment: Please, remove the code  "PDF=(1/normFactor)*PDF", if you want number,not probability.

Comment: And, If you want bin size 1,  please change the code "delta=10" as "delta=1".

Comment: Thanks a lot. But because there are only 1 or 2 peaks in the graph, I wanted to find out the plot in log scale. I have tried `set(gca,'zscale','log')`, but nothing happens. Could you kindly tell me how to do that? Thanks.